# Nested foreach statements to access

Tags: c#, foreach

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with this code?  VS2012 is rejecting the second foreach statement.

I get

```
"type or namespace name 'grid' could not be found..."
```

and

```
"invalid token 'foreach' in class..."  

public static void go(DataTable grid)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in grid.Rows);
    }
           foreach (DataColumn col in grid.columns);
    }
```

I get the same error for:

```
public static void go(DataTable grid)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in grid.Rows);
    }
           foreach (DataColumn col in row.columns);
    }
```

My VS has been crashing periodically (actually, first real "blue screen of death" that I've seen since before Windows XP) and I've had some unusual behaviors like controls disappearing from forms.

So, who is suffering distorted code logic, me or VS?

Comment: Check your formatting.

Comment: <pre> public static void go(DataTable grid)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in grid.Rows);
        }
               foreach (DataColumn col in grid.columns);
        }

Comment: If you entered your code examples correctly, notice that you have semi-colons directly after the `foreach` statements. If that isn't what your code actually looks like, please re-enter and re-format it.

Answer (score 3):

Your nested foreach block doesn't have closure:

It should be:

```
public static void go(DataTable grid)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in grid.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn col in row.columns)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The second foreach seems just randomly placed in your code file. It needs to be inside the function

```
        public static void go(DataTable grid)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in grid.Rows)
            {
               foreach (DataColumn col in row.columns)
               {
               }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra `}` right before the second `foreach`. That one is closing the method, so the second `foreach` is out of the method definition and that is a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is hard to read without proper indentation, but your foreach's are not nested. That is they are completely separate, so 'grid' is not visible to the second foreach block.